there is a issue occurs while creating segment

 $response = $client->lists->createSegment("46ec78750d", [
    'name' => $request->name,
    'options' => [
        'match' => 'any',
        'conditions' => [
            [
                'condition_type' => 'EmailAddress',
                'field' => 'merge0',
                'op' => 'in',
                'value' => $emails
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

I am trying to create a segment in Mailchimp using their API. Above's the code I'm using
However, I encounter the following error:
Error creating segment: Client error: `POST https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/46ec78750d/segments`resulted in a `400 Bad Request`response: {
    "type": "https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/",
    "title": "Invalid Resource",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "The r (truncated...)

